# Sharing Prism Views between multiple Views that contain the same region

Tags: silverlight, prism, silverlight-5.0, prism-4

I am trying to achieve the following pattern where the ContentRegion can have either ModuleShellView or Module2ShellView loaded/Active at any moment in time.

Module2ShellView has no reference to View1 but cause View1 has been registered to Region1 it is loaded into the Module2ShellView when that view is loaded into the ContentRegion but I want both ModuleShellViews to share the same instance of View1.

I want to be able to switch between both ModuleShellViews

```
MainShell
--ContentRegion
----ModuleShellView
------Region1
--------View1
----Module2ShellView
------Region1
--------View1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you would want `View1` instance to be available for both `ModuleShellViews`. One way to do this is to register `View1` as **Singleton** in the **Container** so each time `View1` is loaded, the container will return always the same instance.

You can find more related information of **View Registration** on the following **Prism** guide chapter:

- [Managing Dependencies between Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec2)

Another alternative to accomplish this scenario would be by decoupling `View1` from the `ContentRegion` where **Navigation** is performed. Below is a possible **View Tree** design which keeps `View1` away from unloading and loading:

```
MainShell:
* Region1
  - View1
* ContentRegion
  - ModuleShellView
  - Module2ShellView
```

I hope this helps.